# User Registration in Laravel: Request or array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I have been using **php** artisan make:auth in Laravel and I notice that in `RegisterController` specifically in this function:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
 //insert registration data here
}
```

---

It always uses `array $data` instead of something else like `(Request $request)`. My question is, is it better to use `array` instead of `Request`? And is it a good practice if I replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses array because it already gets `Request` model in upper function so it is not good idea to pass full request to other functions when you get it. It's a big data and you don't need it with cookies and other stuff... You only need input data so you convert it to `array` and pass it to other functions.